# images changing the position of other elements on being zoomed

Tags: html, css

I am making a page in which there will be array of images. I need the images to be zoomed when the mouse is hovered and i got it successfully through java script. But the problem is when the image gets enlarged the position of the other images is also getting changed.
  I want such that the zoomed image does not change the position of other images like **Google Images**...  that is i want the zoomed image to come over the beside images....any help please... 
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use absolute positioning and z-index.

HTML

```
<div class="container"><img src="#" /></div>
<div class="container"><img src="#" /></div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
     position: relative;
}
.container img {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 0;
}
.container img:hover {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid making use of percentage for giving height and width. I have experienced it too. Instead provide height and width in "pixels(px)". That would serve better and the solution for your query.